# SSIS Excel definite cell with rows

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, row, cell

I have an Excel spreadsheet like this:

```
C1 - 100100
G1 - 01.01.2015
H1 - 15.05.2015
```

From A5:

```
ID         animal    sales
123123       bear      100
213213       zebra     200 
321321       lion      150
```

and I need to move data into a SQL Server database using SSIS. The resulting table should look like

```
ID      Animal   Sales    Date1       Date2         Region
123123  bear     100      01.01.2015   15.05.2015   100100
213213  zebra    200      01.01.2015   15.05.2015   100100
321321  lion     150      01.01.2015   15.05.2015   100100
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error?   What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I couldn't add values of C1, G1, H1 to each rows. I used "UNION ALL" , "MERGE" , but didn't get result

Answer (score 1):

The way I have handled this problem in the past is to:

- Define 2 Excel connection managers, one with FirstRowHasColumnName to True and one where that is false.
- Create an Excel Source, use the first connection manager, and point it to your rowset TableName$A5:ZZ,
- Create 3 more Excel Sources which will point to the rowsets TableName$C1:C1, TableName$G1:G1, and TableName$H1:H1
- Add a derived column to each of these, set it, and then do a union based on your derived column.  Do this for your original source as well.

When doing this I had problems with the metadata for the column names for the C1, G1, and H1 sources, so it took some fiddling to finally get it to work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hcaelxxam, how do I need to set derived column?

Comment: Just add a derived column to each source, name it ID, and set its value to 1.  Then do your Union based on the column ID in each source.